# Send an email with Multipart (csv attachment and HTML) in MarkLogic

Tags: javascript, marklogic, multipart, marklogic-10

I would like to send an email with multipart using MarkLogic. Multipart contains csv attachment and HTML.I am able to attach CSV file but not able to show HTML content in multipart. In below code HTML content are being processed as an attachment without any data.

```js
var boundary = "blahblahblah" + xdmp.random();
var contentType = "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary;

var att1 = xdmp.base64Encode(exportToCsv());

var part1 = "Notification and Alert";

var  htmlString = '<html> <body> <p> Tracking Details </p>  </body> </html> '
    
var part2 = {
             "Content-Type": "csv/text",
             "Content-Disposition":"attachment",
             "filename":"Notification "+queryDate+".csv",
             "Content-Transfer-Encoding":"base64",
             "attachment":att1
            };
var part3 = {
             "Content-Type": "text/html",
             "Content-Disposition":"inline",
             "Content":htmlString
            };

var from = {"name":"Team", "address":"zzzz@zzz.com"};
var to = {"addresses":[mailId]};
var subject = "Tracking Update"+" "+queryDate;
var message = {
               "from":from,
               "to":to,
               "subject": subject,
               "content-type":contentType,
               "content":{
                          "boundary":boundary,
                          "parts":[part1,part2,part3]
                         }
};
```

Comment: Are you intending to send the HTML as an attachment or for it to display inline? You have `Content-Disposition: "inline"` Might need `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` instead?

Comment: @MadsHansen Thanks for help!!I want to display inline. I will try Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable and update

Comment: I tried 
var part3 = {
"Content-Type": "text/html",
"Content-Transfer-Encoding":"quoted-printable",
 "Content":'<html> <body> <p> Tracking </p>  </body> </html> '
            };
Is Content field being correct to be used to pass html string? Or I am missing anything here? As HTML data is not getting displayed in email

Comment: Hi @MadsHansen I tried var part3 = { "Content-Type": "text/html", "Content-Transfer-Encoding":"quoted-printable", "Content":'<html> <body> <p> Tracking </p> </body> </html> ' }; Is Content field being correct to be used to pass html string? Or I am missing anything here? As HTML data is not getting displayed in email